# Unlock HR user in Oracle 19c/18c/12c?

Tags: oracle

While trying to unlock the HR user, I am getting an error saying, “user HR does not exist”.

Comment: Walkthrough here: http://www.rebellionrider.com/how-to-unlock-hr-user-in-oracle-database-19c/

Comment: Did you install the demo schemas when you created the database? Which container are you connected to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Unlocking sample accounts like HR in Oracle 19c/18c/12c**

*Edit tnsnames.ora  file located at %db_home%\network\admin*

*Add TNS ORCLPDB like below-highlighted block*
[image]

*Open CMD as Administrator and execute below command*

```
C:\>lsnrctl reload
```

*Open CMD and execute SQLPlus with below command to login as SYSDBA*

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> sqplus / as sysdba
```

*Run below SQL commands to Unlock your Schema*

```
  ALTER SESSION SET container = ORCLPDB;
```

*Check if the pluggable database is opened ?*

```
SELECT name, open_mode FROM v$pdbs;
```

> *To open your pluggable database Skip If Already open*

```
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE open;
```

*Unlock HR user*

```
ALTER USER hr IDENTIFIED BY <your_password> ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
conn
username hr@orclpdb
password <your_password>
Connected.
```

*Connected means you can access HR schema lets start*

> Now you will be able to access HR schema

```
select * from tab;
```